# xamarin android (end of central directory record not found)

Tags: xamarin

I am developing an app using xamarin android, but when I build my app I getting this error, What should I do. thanks

```
    End of Central Directory record could not be found.
             at  system.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
    at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
    at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
    at   Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore.LoadResource(String resourceFullPath, String assemblyName)
    at Xamarin.Build.Download.BaseXamarinBuildResourceRestore.MergeResources(IAssemblyResolver resolver, String originalAsmPath, String mergedAsmPath, String assemblyName, List`1 resourceItems)   Doctors
```

Comment: I also encounter this problem. I load a very basic tutorial android program and build it. Then I just add "Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" nuget packages to the project and when build it, get the above error message.

Comment: @Yashil -  Did you manage to resolve this - i.e. get it to build with Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging included as a package?